# How to specify MajorRevision of .NET Assembly?

Tags: .net, versioning

Currently, I am using `AssemblyVersionAttribute` to specify assembly versions of compiled assemblies.
However, `AssemblyVersionAttribute` allows to specify only 16bit revision [[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). How can I specify `MajorRevision` greater than zero?

Comment: No, `MajorRevision` number: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.majorrevision%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MajorRevision` and `MinorRevision` properties of the `Version` class are calculated from the `Revision` property, as `Revision >> 16` and `Revision & 0xffff` respectively (try opening **mscorlib** in Reflector).

Assembly versioning does not support revision numbers greater than 16 bits in length. This data is stored in a 16 bit section of the assembly binary. In other words, assembly versions support only a subset of the capabilities of the `Version` class. You can see this in a hex editor: setting the version to, say, 1.0.0.65534, will give the hex bytes in the compiled DLL `0100 0000 0000 feff`. Trying to insert a value in the following two bytes and then inspecting the assembly does not increase the version number beyond 16 bits.

Comment: How can I specify 65535 to (-1)? To say according the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.revision.aspx that `Revision` is undefined? (Omitting the number sets it to 0.)

Comment: Not sure I understand your first question - are you looking for an explanation of the negative numbers?

Comment: If it's not possible to specify `MajorRevision`, I would like set `Revision` to 0xFFFF, which according to the link above should mean that Revision is undefined. However standard use of `AssemblyVersionAttribute` allows only integers from 0 to 0xFFFE. So I am looking for some wildcard (e.g. '?', similarly to '*') or other way to specify it.

Comment: Not possible via `AssemblyVersionAttribute`, for sure. Sorry.

Comment: Where can I see this via ILSpy or Reflector? Is there another way to specify it, e.g. say it another way to compiler (better) or use some toolkit to modify the version after it is compiled (worse)?

Comment: I've not been able to find a definitive answer to this, but my suspicion is that it is not possible with an assembly version.

Comment: Maybe someone else will know where to see that. Or how to force the compiler or how to change the version after the assembly gets compiled.

Comment: Well, hope someone can help, but I can only find reference to setting an assembly version at build time using the `AssemblyVersionAttribute`, which definitely doesn't support what you are trying to do. Fingers crossed for you...

Comment: Which assembly contains processing of `AssemblyVersionAttribute`? Reflecting that may provide more information. Or is it written in native code?

Comment: `AssemblyVersionAttribute` stores the version as a string and returns it as such; it does no processing on it itself (it's in mscorlib if you want a look). I suspect it's only really used by csc.exe, which is not itself a .NET exe and therefore can't be reflected out by Reflector.